# How to get contract address when receiving an ERC-721 token in a contract?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, nft, erc-721, interfaces

I'm writing an NFT staking contract and I want my contract to accept NFTs **only** from 3 specific contracts. I have implemented `IERC721Receiver` and the `onERC721Received` function successfully fires. What is the best way to get the contract address of a received token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token that is being transferred will call the `IERC721Receiver` methods. Therefore you can use `msg.sender` to detect the address of the token that is being transfered.

> The ERC721 smart contract calls this function on the recipient after a `transfer`. This function MAY throw to revert and reject the transfer. Return of other than the magic value MUST result in the transaction being reverted.

Taken from https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

Be aware that for ERC-721 tokens this only applies to the `safeTransferFrom` methods. It is still possible to transfer the tokens to your contracts by using the `transferFrom` method.

Comment: Thank you so much it definitely works. Regarding the last part of your answer, I'm handling the staking logic on the ```onERC721Received ``` function and I'm calling the ```safeTransferFrom``` function from the ERC-721 contract on the website so... Is there anything extra that I can do except warn users not to manually transfer tokens to the staking address?

Comment: Require that msg.sender is equal to one of your 3 addresses? Otherwise it will revert the transaction with an error message of your choice.